# Why release a C++ library as a native DLL for windows?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, operating-system

Edit: this question was originally asked in a way that didn't make it as obvious what I was looking for in discussion. A new question has been posted here: [How does copying native-DLLs on windows to the executable directory share code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78028325/how-does-copying-native-dlls-on-windows-to-the-executable-directory-share-code)

I appreciate the thought that others contributed below.  The original question was asking what benefit DLLs have over static libraries given that the convention on windows is to copy DLLs to executable directories. While I think some things in linux make it easier to maintain libraries in different directories, that's a separate debate and that wasn't the main point of the question. Since it seemed like that's what discussion the original question was generating, I posted the new one.

Comment: Back in the days I think MS had envisioned that multiple applications would share the same DLL. This was also true in the early days of Windows, when coding in something like VB involved first chasing down some godforsaken DLL not delivered with the IDE from somewhere and then telling the IDE to use that one. Horror stories...

Comment: `dll` are the windows equivalent of Linux shared objects and have the exact same purpose. They are not required to be in the same directory than the executable by the way. Windows has destination paths where to look for dlls (system32 for 64 bits dlls, syswow64 for 32 bits dlls... yeah it's a long story). And it's the same for Linux except that you can extend those destination paths through the  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. Maybe you can do the same on Windows.

Comment: Anyway, hard drives have evolved spectacularly since the earliest days of Windows. Where there used to be a hd space of 40Mb in total , the .NET runtime gunk alone is now about 10 times larger than that. So using DLLs to save space probably doesn't make much sense any longer.

Comment: The system directories or PATH variable feel too intrusive of an expectation. Unix can link an absolute path so it doesn't need to pollute a top level system directory.

Comment: DLLs  and unix shared objects are equivalent.    And it's not only windows developers who copy a version of DLLs (or shared objects) in the same directory as their program.     There's been a stink over last couple of years because Ubuntu liinux started covertly forcing use of Flatpak, which essentially installs programs and objects they depend on in the same way.

Comment: One advatage of using DLLs: you can update them without the need to build (specifically: link) the executable that uses them. This can make deplyment of updates for a large product a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed an incorrect assumption of yours: a DLL does not need to be in the same folder as the executable that uses it. The alternatives on Windows are:

- all applications can use DLLs that live in a folder listed in the `PATH` environment variable.
  This is how a DLL usually is made accessible by several applications at once on a computer.
- if the application looks for its required DLLs in an explicitly set path.
  That latter option is done thanks to the [SetDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function.

This answers the "how" part of the question: a consumer may choose whether they prefer managing a given library by copying it next to each of the executables that use it or by updating `PATH`. Generally speaking, the more central a DLL is, the more likely it is `PATH` will be updated.

---

Now to answer the "why would you prefer a shared library: the space it can save on disk is indeed an historical reason, irrelevant nowadays.
However, there remain cases where shared libraries help achieving things that are impossible with static libraries: for instance, maintaining [binary compatible](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B) versions of a DLL can make a lot of sense, especialy from the point of view of system/network administrations. By definition, binary compatibility does not exist for static libraries, since the executables need to be recompiled.

Just like above, maintaining compatibility across versions is more useful, the more central your DLL is.
If your library is used by e.g. 50 applications on a single system and/or if your libraries is used by a third party selling a software, **having the ability to correct a security issue without having to recompile 50 applications or without having to wait for the third party to upgrade their executable** is a big plus, for obvious reasons.

Achieving this requires a lot of technical knowledge but is definitely useful.

Comment: Did you read the whole question? I understand that's an option, but its also not a common industry practice. It's a bit annoying to expect everyone who uses your library to update PATH or write explicit lookup code.

Comment: @NicholasGulachek Yes but it's the way it is, it works the same for Linux shared objects. If you don't want to update the path, or set an executable rpath or whatever, you need to put your dll (or .so on Linux) into the system default location(s). It's not specific to dlls.

Comment: @NicholasGulachek What do you mean ? Ld look for a bunch of default paths and for what you give to it (via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). If you put your .so somewhere that is not in the system default (i.e. the ld defaults) and you don't specify it in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or in rpath or whatever, it won't link, period.

Comment: I can do more digging later, but my understanding is that a shred object can reference absolute paths or rpath of direct dependencies and not all transitive dependencies, so it seems more scalable on linux.

Comment: @NicholasGulachek The fact that you can use `PATH` does not mean that you must use it: you provide your library to a client and it is up to them how they want to manage it. Therefore, nobody has to "expect" anything from everyone.

Comment: @Atmo, at that point it seems like a better API experience to use a static library and not expect the consumer to have extra complications. The question is more about why I should use a DLL and not how to use a DLL

Comment: If I need to tell consumers to add a copy task of all transitive dependencies or update PATH, that is an added expectation.

Comment: If your DLL is binary compatible across versions (see [here](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B)), then your new versions can be deployed without a need to recompile anything. In some contexts, it can be more useful than it sounds. Does it count as a valid reason for you?

Comment: And regarding your last comment, I do not see what you mean: your consumers will have to do something with the DLL, either save it with their executable along with its dependency or update PATH for your DLL, its dependencies or both, and they can choose. It is one or the other, there is no option to do nothing... And I don't think you need to tell them anything either. So nothing is being *added*.

Comment: I'll have to think about it. I appreciate all of the discussion but need to go for now. My gut feeling is that this is less beneficial with the windows convention of copying the DLL everywhere but I think it depends on how the person installing the executable expects it to get updated dependencies and a copy task I agree is quicker/simpler than a compile

Comment: A shared library might be less beneficial on Windows than on other OS (can't judge) but it does not mean that within Windows, a DLL is useless or detrimental per se, compared to providing a static library. These are 2 independent topics.

Comment: Yeah. I think this discussion has helped me see that the way I asked the question, I made it difficult for readers to understand what I actually wanted to know. Thanks for the feedback. I think im gonna delete this and ask a new revised question / answer because it will be confusing to edit this one

Comment: I was actually on my way to edit my answer when you commented. See if it matches what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to answer correctly to your question.

**From the historical point of view**

I think we have:

1. static linking (various copies of even the system libs)
2. dynamic linking (try to avoid copies of libraries, less space needed, etc)
3. dynamic libs everywhere even copies of in the case of macOS application bundles for example (I have no doubt it is almost the same for Windows). mac OS do not even permit static linking for an entire executable.

At time 2 a problem arose: managing versions and dependencies. A mess as we know.

At time 3 an application bundle is self-contained, so you can safely remove applications without asking each time «do I need to remove some unuseful external library too»? Everything is contained in a unique directory (roughly).

**Some possible rationale.**

Some libraries are general-purpose, and these may be shared for the benefit of coherence, smaller memory footprint, etc. Think of something like ffmpeg, which provides a library to manipulate streams. So it is better to construct a DLL such that many other softwares rely on the single installation of it and share the code at runtime. Of course this is not a requirement and you can distribute an application with its own copy of ffmpeg lib (static or not).

I don't know exactly how it works under Windows, but MacOS applications are structured as bundles which contains almost all "private" frameworks/libs. You may think this is not more different than having static libs and that is almost true, but an application is not a single executable. An application may provide different modes of execution through several ways of calling it through the user interface (running the full application, using it as a system service, quicklook functionality, automator plugins, etc). So sharing the code of the libs for this "application" does make sense. That also let the update of an application only considering part of it (some libs/frameworks, some executables, etc).

Finally, lazy linking is one of the benefits of shared libs: don't consider linking until it is necessary to do so (defer the "true" linking at runtime), this even if a good OS may not load all the code at once but on demand (lazy loading of code).