# How does copying native-DLLs on windows to the executable directory share code?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

Here's my background understanding of the relevant C/C++ library landscape for shared libraries (`.so`, `.dylib`, `.dll`):

On unix-like platforms, the most common convention is to install shared libraries in a dedicated system directory like `/usr/local/lib`. Other linked images that use this library will load the library from that location.  This makes it obvious how the code is shared between executables.

On Windows, the convention seems to be that you copy all of your transitive dependencies to the directory of the executable you're building.  This makes it difficult to see how the code is actually being shared.

I'm not questioning that it's possible to set something up on Windows to share the DLL across multiple executables, but the question I'm interested in is: **does this convention have any code-sharing benefit? Does it provide any code sharing beyond what a static library would provide?**

Comment: Linking as static might not be possible due to some licenses.

Comment: "*On unix-like platforms, the most common convention is to install shared libraries in a dedicated system directory like `/usr/local/lib`*" -- that is indeed very common, but it is becoming less so.  And it is in fact *not* the norm for third-party libraries on MacOS, which, as a derivative of BSD Unix, is certainly "unix-like".

Comment: Maybe your project itself has multiple executables. At work my projects do have 5 or so separate executables.

Comment: Ha @drescherjm almost had the same answer at the same time!

Comment: One benefit that's not about sharing is that it lets you "upgrade" part of an application by just swapping a DLL, and storing them beside the application avoids naming conflicts. Size mattered a lot back when applications and upgrades were distributed through floppies or phone lines. (The 63-floppy full installation of Word 6 was really not fun at all.)

Comment: The loading of dependent DLLs may also be delayed vs. loading ALL dependent DLLs at startup of an executable.  This helps with load times.  If the app is huge with tons of features, but where (like most huge monolithic apps) most users use the "core" 5% of the application, but then each user sparingly uses the other 95%.

Comment: Dlls could be also used to isolate some code rather than share it, i.g. use different versions of the same library without conflicts.

Comment: Check out this excellent talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_enXuIxuNV4. Linking dynamically on windows is not just about sharing code among executables.

Comment: *On unix-like platforms, the most common convention is to install shared libraries in a dedicated system directory like `/usr/local/lib`.* `/usr/local/lib` is used by no one delivering commercial/enterprise-level software.  At best, a full, independent directory tree under `/usr/local`, such as `/usr/local/cuda/...` is installed.  Quite a bit of commercial software gets installed in `/opt` per [the Linux FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where multiple executables are built as part of a project in the same output directory.  In this case, even though transitive dependencies are copied to the executable directory, they are still shared between the different executables of the same project.